# When rendering a white surface appears under my object. Moving the object changes nothing

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

It appears white at the bottom only when rendering the image. I am using Cycles for this.
This is the issue.
[image]
I am using the Blender 2.82a.

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: hard to say, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/